# -WebApplication while installing the WSP with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I need some information regarding the PowerShell commands.
I have created one WSP, and while installing that WSP I need to add **-WebApplication**.(It's mandatory some times / some times not)
So what factor/source is causing to force the command to add the **-WebApplication** in the install command.

Some times I don't need to add the **-WebApplication**.

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity Test.wsp  -WebApplication http://pc07:0707 -GACDeployment
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution can be deployed into two different levels:

- farm
- web application

Prior to the actual installation, SharePoint tries to determine if your particular `.wsp` contains resources, scoped to web application. If you solution does contain such resources, you need to use `-WebApplication` switch.

Which types of resources (or deployment artifacts) are considered by SharePoint as web application scoped:

- Web application scoped features
- Safe control entries (because in that case SharePoint needs to update `web.config` for corresponding web application)
- `.dll` deployed to the `bin` folder
- May be some other elements

Comment: Can you please elaborate it? Which .dll's goes in the Web Application Scope?

Comment: When dealing with code inside SharePoint solution, you can deploy your `dll` into the GAC (most common option) or into the web application's `bin` folder. Each web application in sharepoint is mapped to corresponding IIS web site, that means that your `dlls` will reside under bin folder for IIS web site, ie `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Portal-80\bin\`. Code inside bin directory is less trusted, that's why usually you put into the GAC